# How to make linked stack generics?

Tags: java, generics

I am doing lab, I viewed a lot of Java Generics example, but I cannot understand it. My goal is achieving Linked Stack. It have 2 files: `IntStack.java` and `IntNode.java`. The part of these code is:

```
public class IntNode {
    private int element = 0;
    private IntNode next = null;
    public IntNode(final int data, final IntNode next) {
        this.element = data;
        this.next = next;
}

public class IntStack {
private IntNode top = null;
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return this.top == null;
}
```

How to convert them to generics type? I know it should use `<T>`,and I write these code, it is correct or not?

```
public class Node<T> {
    private T element;
    private Node<T> next = null;
    public Node(final T data,final Node next) {
        this.element = data;
        this.next = next;
    }
}
```

Comment: `Node next` shouldn't use raw type, thus should be parametrized with `T`: `Node<T> next` .

Comment: @LuCio Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You are close. The `Node` parameter of the `Node` constructor should also be parameterized:

```
public class Node<T> {   
    private T element;
    private Node<T> next = null;
    public Node(final T data,final Node<T> next) {
        this.element = data;
        this.next = next;
    }
}
```